# Firebase Chat using my own server instead

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an application and now i want to implement chat functionality, i learned about firebase. But i need authentication. How do i achieve chat functionality of firebase but using my own server.Now i read about custom authentication but i received error that my Token pattern was wrong. Can someone explain to me that what i want is even possible and if so ,then am i using the correct way i.e custom authentication. And how do i generate a valid token. Thank you.

I know there is nothing wrong with the code but just to be sure.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(jsonObject.getString(ResponseParam.AUTH_TOKEN))
    .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        try {
            saveDataInPreference(jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                                                               
    } else {
        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
});
```

Comment: If code is known good (was working before custom auth, eg)... I'd make sure your token is good first thing.  Paste it in at https://jwt.io/ and verify that everything is valid.  According to firebase docs, there is nothing special about it, it's a standard jwt.

Comment: thanx , btw i asked if this is the approach that should be used so was i right?

Comment: Let us know if the token is good first.  Nothing jumps out at me but I'll dig in more if the token passes.

Comment: i tried to put my token in it, it didnt recognize it

Comment: Yeah I figured.  You'll need to look at your token generation logic and get it in a valid JWT format..  I imagine once your token is good everything will work as expected.

Comment: How do i generate this in JWT format , i searched it a little but couldn't understand it, unfortunately my web guy is bzy so i thought maybe i'll understand a little myself first, then explain to him

Comment: https://jwt.io is a really great resource for this.  https://jwt.io/introduction/ goes over each part, encoding, what is required, etc... We use Azure, so that's pretty much the best I can do for you - I haven't created my own yet, but it seems pretty simple.

Comment: just create custom token with firebase admin sdk https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk  It just needs a unique id,

Comment: per https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens ---"To create custom tokens with the Firebase Admin SDK, you must have a service account." ... Possible issue - otherwise yeah that works, and easier.

Comment: i tried a proper token, using my email and name, that website didnt give error this time but android gave the same error

Comment: what do you mean service account